# Unable to crawl all of a sudden using SMB

Tags: google-search-appliance

Using a google search appliance (mini) and all of a sudden my SMB crawling has stopped.  I always get this error when trying to test connection via the web console:

returncode 404, should be 200

I found this script and smbcrawler.py works fine on it, but my appliance still can't crawl.

https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit

Nothing has changed as far as i'm aware, it just stopped working one day and i can't understand why.  Logs aren't really showing me anything.

Server is a windows 2008 file server, share is open to everybody.  From what i understand, device is setup to crawl SMB only so UNC crawling isn't an option, but if i use \\Share it still gives the same error.  I'm sure credentials are correct.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

Turned out some sort of windows update or other disabled SMBv1.  Once i turned it back on the file server, everything started working again.